# Pushing data into Highcharts Series in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, sapui5

I have an JSON object with 1000 customers and I want to push their names into the pie chart of highcharts. Unfortunately, the name-attribute of the customers are not displayed in the chart. I got the following chart:
[image: Piechart]`

[image: Overview Object]

As you can see, I have an object with more than 99 objects (total number 1000) with a Customer_ID and Customer_Description.
With the following code I try to push 10 objects into a series object where it should be passed to the series attribute of the chart:

```
        var customer_gesamt = [];
        var customer_teil = {};
        customer_teil.data = [];   
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            customer_teil.name = customer_descriptions[i].CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION;
            customer_teil.color = '#' + i + '0D0FF';
            customer_teil.data.push(i);

        }
        customer_gesamt.push(customer_teil);
```

The resulting customer_gesamt looks like in the following. I think the problem is the wrong pushing of the data into this object.
[image: customer_gesamt]
My aim is to have an object with 10 customers with their ids, description and their speicific color and to push them into the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You should push name and color into the point object, this way:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        customer_teil.data.push({
            y: i,
            name: customer_descriptions[i].CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION,
            color: '#' + i + '0D0FF'
        });
    }
```

PS: `y: i` will set an index, not the value.